# pandas read_csv dtype definitions : int, int64, 'Int64'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, file-io

Can someone point me in the good direction to understand the (seeming) inconsistency in the way to define dtype during pandas.read_csv ?

dtype = int                     #  --> produces error if blank values
dtype = int32, int64, and Int64 # --> are not defined
dtype = 'Int64'                 # --> correctly reads csv file as ints and with blank values

- Why are quotes required for 'Int64' but not for str, float, int, object ?
- I did not find a reference that clearly defines the valid list of dtypes for pandas.read_csv. Does this exist somewhere ?

```
import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

MY_DTYPES = {
    'date_string': str,
    'description': str,
#    'ValueError_Integer_column_has_NA_values': int,
#    'int32_is_not_defined': int32,
#    'int64_is_not_defined': int64,
#    'Int_64_is_not_defined': Int64,
    'Int64_with_quote_and_NaN': 'Int64', # !! THIS WORKS !!
    'quantity': float,
    'total': float}

f = 'dataset.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype = MY_DTYPES)
```

```
df.head(15)
   date_string  description  Int64_with_quote_and_NaN  quantity   total
0       201202   "Lorem ips                       513     186.0     4.0
1       200909     um dolor                       601     502.0    13.0
2       201701          sit                       NaN     462.0    20.0
3       201401        amet,                       513     934.0   206.0
4       201202  consectetur                       513       NaN   194.0
5       200710   adipiscing                       602     570.0   930.0
6       200501        elit,                       513     160.0     NaN
7       200808          sed                       NaN     508.0   461.0
8       201906           do                       513     316.0     3.0
9       201009      eiusmod                       NaN     994.0     1.0
10         NaN          NaN                       513     709.0     0.0
11      201905   incididunt                       513     318.0     6.0
12      201612           ut                       513       NaN     1.0
13      201506       labore                       513     901.0    74.0
14      201002          NaN                       625      33.0   739.0
```

Comment: `int`, `str`, and `float` are Python types. They are from the `builtins` so when you refer to them by their names you won't get a NameError. For convenience, when you pass Python types, pandas uses the numpy types corresponding to them (`np.int64` for example). When you use `int64` you get a NameError because it is not from the builtins. That's why you need to use quotation marks to pass them as strings.

Comment: Also, `np.int64` and the nullable `pd.Int64Dtype()` are different types. The former cannot contain nan's. `'Int64'` is an alias of `pd.Int64Dtype()`.

Comment: Hi @ayhan thanks for this info. I did not find a reference that clearly defines the valid list of dtypes for pandas.read_csv. Does this exist somewhere ?

Comment: Here is the list of dtypes:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes

Answer (score 0):

> Why int64 requires quotes?

Since the mentioned dtype is not a built-in dtype of python `'int64', 'Int64', 'int32'` are strings representing of specific NumPy dtypes which requires quotes.

Correct way: `dtype={'column_name': 'Int64'}`

Valid dtype options:

- Built-in python dtypes: `int`, `float`, `str`, `bool`, `object`.
- NumPy dtypes(as strings): `'int8'`, `'int16'`, `'int32'`, `'int64'`, `'float16'`, `'float32'`, `'float64'`, `'string_'`, `'category'`, `'datetime64[ns]'`.